# Make use of PostgreSQL 10 multi-column statistics when planning index scans

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10, index-statistics

I'm using PostgreSQL 10 and am trying to optimize query performance on a large table (~70M rows). The query looks like:

```
SELECT *
FROM large_table
-- many joins --
WHERE col_3 = 'particular date'::date
AND col_4 = 'particular date'::date;
```

Both conditions separately return ~100K rows each and results overlap ~99%, so the query returns ~100K rows as well. Both columns are indexed.

`col_3` and `col_4` are highly correlated and I have already created statistics to make Postgres aware of it using new statistics in postgres 10:

```
CREATE STATISTICS stat_large_table_dates (DEPENDENCIES, NDISTINCT)
ON col_3, col_4, col_5
FROM large_table;
```

I can see the statistics are calculated and postgres indeed believes col_3 and col_4 to be highly correlated when I run the query below:

```
SELECT stxname, stxkeys, stxdependencies                                                  
FROM pg_statistic_ext
WHERE stxname = 'stat_large_table_dates';
```

However, indexes seem to be unaware of it. The query planner expects to match 120-140 rows during index scan depending on types of indexes I try. In turn, all following steps of the plan vastly underestimate the row counts.

For the queries with only one condition it correctly expects ~100K rows. If we do the (simplified) planner math, 100K rows from 70M row table, probability a random row will match is ~0.0014. With an assumption that both conditions are completely independent we multiply both probabilities for `AND` operator, so we end up expecting the probability a random row will match to be ~0.000002. For a 70M row table it would be ~142 rows. It is clear index scans are not aware of collected statistics.

**My question is**: is there a way in PostgreSQL 10 to make use of the new statistics in index scans?

**RE: execution plans**

I've excluded a large part of the plan that is not related to the `large_table`, but kept the final step. It's a large plan and everything depending on the section bellow expects to work with 126 rows, but actual row count is close to 100K.

The indices initially have a correct expectation of row counts, but starts underestimating the row count when joined.

`col_3` and `col_4` in in different indices:

```
Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=18395.22..32724.14 rows=126 width=1463) (actual time=4719.101..67529.618 rows=98376 loops=1)
Join Filter: ((lt.col_4 >= t2.col_from) AND (lt.col_4 <= t2.col_to))
Rows Removed by Join Filter: 149604
Buffers: shared hit=4431777 read=29497, temp read=9835 written=11344
...
    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on large_table lt  (cost=3346.64..3855.37 rows=126 width=201) (actual time=32.990..1155.536 rows=98376 loops=1)
            Recheck Cond: (('some val'::date = col_3) AND (col_4 = 'similar val'::date))
            Filter: ((col_2)::text <> 'third val'::text)
            Rows Removed by Filter: 787
            Heap Blocks: exact=9976
            Buffers: shared hit=3 read=10358
            ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=3346.64..3346.64 rows=127 width=0) (actual time=30.837..30.837 rows=0 loops=1)
                Buffers: shared hit=3 read=382
                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_large_table_col_3  (cost=0.00..1372.11 rows=103481 width=0) (actual time=18.392..18.392 rows=101870 loops=1)
                        Index Cond: ('some val'::date = col_3)
                        Buffers: shared hit=1 read=128
                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on clst_idx_large_table_col_4  (cost=0.00..1974.22 rows=110621 width=0) (actual time=12.013..12.013 rows=99163 loops=1)
                        Index Cond: (col_4 = 'similar val'::date)
                        Buffers: shared hit=2 read=254
...
Planning time: 21.125 ms
Execution time: 67577.366 ms
```

This is with an index including all columns of the filter:

```
Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=15212.44..29388.67 rows=124 width=1463) (actual time=2145.272..60926.305 rows=98376 loops=1)
Join Filter: ((lt.col_4 >= t2.col_from) AND (lt.col_4 <= t2.col_to))
Rows Removed by Join Filter: 149604
Buffers: shared hit=4460931, temp read=9835 written=11344
...
    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on large_table lt  (cost=185.29..690.02 rows=124 width=201) (actual time=19.381..102.327 rows=98376 loops=1)
            Recheck Cond: (('particular date'::date = col_3) AND (col_4 = 'particular date'::date))
            Filter: ((col_2)::text <> 'some val'::text)
            Rows Removed by Filter: 787
            Heap Blocks: exact=9976
            Buffers: shared hit=10018
            ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_large_table_cols_2_3_4  (cost=0.00..185.26 rows=126 width=0) (actual time=18.008..18.008 rows=99163 loops=1)
                Index Cond: (('particular date'::date = col_3) AND (col_4 = 'particular date'::date))
                Buffers: shared hit=42
...
Planning time: 17.612 ms
Execution time: 60973.123 ms
```

**RE: contents of pg_statistic_ext**

```
stxname: stat_large_table_dates 
stxkeys: 3 4 5
stxkind: {d,f}
stxndistinct: {"3, 4": 1630, "3, 5": 1631, "4, 5": 813, "3, 4, 5": 1631}
stxdependencies: {"3 => 4": 1.000000, "3 => 5": 0.998920, "4 => 3": 0.000025, "4 => 5": 0.998907, "3, 4 => 5": 0.998920, "3, 5 => 4": 1.000000, "4, 5 => 3": 0.000027}
```

- In reality 3 => 4 is less than 100% correlation, but it's close;
- 4 => 3 is surprisingly low here;

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plans](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) (with and without the statistics) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers)`** (not just a "simple" explain). [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) or upload the plan to https://explain.depesz.com

Comment: What specifically do you see in pg_statistic_ext ?